# slideToggle( ) effect gone bad

Tags: jquery, css

I am really new to web design, and have been trying to replicate this slideToggle () effect I seen in a course I took with code school. So bottom line is when you press a button, the photo's appear and then when you mouse over the photo's, text appears with a description of the photo. I think the problem is with the css because it was not included in the course jQuery on code school. So if anybody could help me with this because the more I play with it the more I gut it, and I am sure it is probably an easy problem, but I have been learning for 2 weeks, and a week of that was spent on this ( on and off) so I have to ask for help!! Here is a link to all included files http://jsfiddle.net/HtRNk/1/ 
hmm looks like I have to include the code right here

CSS:

```
ul{
    list-style-type:none;
}
ul li {
    display: inline;
}

.photos{

    display:none;
}
span{
    font-size:10px;
    color:#CCCCCC;
    position:relative;
    right:150px;
    bottom:3px;
    display: none;
}

img{
    width:150px;
    height:137px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
function showPhotos(){
    $(this).find('span').slideToggle();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    //EVENT HANDLER FOR CLICK EFFECT

    $('#teams').on('click','button',function(){
    $('.photos').slideToggle();
  });

    $('.photos').on('mouseenter','li',showPhotos);
    $('.photos').on('mouseleave','li',showPhotos);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="teams">
   <h2>My Favourite Sports Teams</h2>
   <p>I love all sports but<em> hockey</em> and <em> football </em>are my favourites</p>
   <button>See team logo's </button>
   <ul class="photos">
     <li>
       <img  src="Sports_site/Images/Canucks/canucks_logo1.gif"><span>Vancouver Canucks (NHL)</span> </li>
     <li>
       <img   src="Sports_site/Images/BCLions/bcLions_logo1.JPG">
       <span> BC Lions (CFL) </span>
     </li>
     <li>
       <img  src="Sports_site/Images/Whitecaps/caps_logo3.jpg">
       <span> Vancouver Whitecaps (MLS) </span>
     </li>
     <li>
       <img src="Sports_site/Images/BlueJays/blue_jays_logo1.gif">
       <span> Toronto BlueJays (MLB) </span>
     </li>
     <li>
       <img src="Sports_site/Images/Seahawks/Glow_seahawks_logo.jpg">
       <span> Seattle Seahawks (NFL) </span>
     </li>
   </ul>
```

Thanks, Dennis

Comment: Forget to mention the problem: When I mouse over the photo's they all move around when displaying the text, I am not a pro but probably has something to do with positioning? Thanks again if you can help

Comment: Your buttons doesn't work - no id on it or jQuery hooked up to it. Why use the "teams" div for your onclick instead of the button?

Comment: You forgot to include jQuery in your fiddle for starters :) - http://jsfiddle.net/HtRNk/3/

Comment: The reason the #teams div was used in the course, was I think to make the button a more specific path? I think in the next part of the course they add more buttons...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is not working, but based on your code above here's my answer.

If you don't want the `li`s to move around when text is added to them (or more specifically, when the `span` is toggled), try using `display: inline-block` and setting a width and height. This way the `li`s don't change size and therefore won't move around when content is added.